# Checking comma in XSLT element

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I am working on below xml and I am trying to transform as CSV output. first element group looks good but second element group has FULL name element and it's having a comma in it. While transforming it's appearing as next column causing issue. Can any body let me know how to deal with the elements having comma in it ? How to identify these type of elements and put double quotes around it ? Any function is available in XSLT for this ? Any Help is much appreciated

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<group>
    <id>989898</id>
    <firstname>steve</firstname>
    <lastname>balmer</lastname>
    <fullname>stevebalmer</fullname>
    <company>Hoyaa</company>
</group>
<group>
    <id>23342</id>
    <firstname>gates</firstname>
    <lastname>satya</lastname>
    <fullname>gates,satya</fullname>
    <company>Jessss</company>
</group>
```

```html
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"></xsl:output>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        
        <xsl:value-of select="/group/id"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="/group/firstname"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="/group/fullname"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="/group/company"/>
        
        
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

To only surround text which does contain commata with double quotes you can make use of a template that matches all `text()` nodes with a predicate:

```
<xsl:template match="group">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="id|firstname|fullname|company"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[contains(.,',')]">
  <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output is:**

```
989898stevestevebalmerHoyaa
23342gates"gates,satya"Jessss
```

To add line-feeds after each item you'd have to add a separate template for normal `text()` nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of identifying specific elements having a `comma` in the value and wrapping only those in `double quotes`, it would be better to have all the values within `double quotes` separated by `comma`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:variable name="quot" select="'&quot;'" />
    <xsl:variable name="comma" select="','" />
    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#xD;'" />

    <xsl:template match="group">
        <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($quot, ., $quot)" />
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="$comma" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
            </xsl:if>       
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
"989898","steve","balmer","stevebalmer","Hoyaa"
"23342","gates","satya","gates,satya","Jessss"
```

Answer (score 0):

With my XSLT processor (xsltproc compiled against libxml 20706, libxslt 10126 and libexslt 815) this code:

```
<xsl:template match="/group">
   &quot;<xsl:value-of select="id"/>&quot;,&quot;<xsl:value-of select="firstname"/>&quot;,&quot;<xsl:value-of select="fullname"/>&quot;,&quot;<xsl:value-of select="company"/>&quot;
</xsl:template>
```

gives this output:

```
"989898","steve","stevebalmer","Hoyaa"
"23342","gates","gates,satya","Jessss"
```

(though I had to nest the groups in a surrounding root tag and adjust the matcher accordingly)